# Drag a draggable when clicking on child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Is it possible to make it so that clicking anywhere on a draggable, if if that means clicking on a child element such as an `<input type="file"/>`?

I've got a [**demo fiddle of what I mean here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RVy7/2/). Notice how if you click on the "Choose file" button, or the text that says "no file chosen", you cannot drag the element.

I want to be able to click anywhere on my `draggable` container and drag the element around, even if I click on the "Choose File" button. I can understand that the click event is firing on the button and probably not the draggable, but why does it work for the `<label>` below? I can click anywhere on the label's text and drag it around.

I also thought maybe changing the `z-index` of my draggable container to be higher than the child element so that maybe the click would register there, but that didn't change anything:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <input type="file" style="z-index:1"/>
</div>

.draggable{
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Is there some way I can set my draggable container to be a transparent overlay so that you always click that (and, therefore can drag)? I realize that this would make the `<input type="file"/>` read-only and ultimately unusable, but that is exactly what I need for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch event:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RVy7/3/)

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
$(".draggable input").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var mdown = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    mdown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", false, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].dispatchEvent(mdown);
});
```

For a more expected behaviour, see:

[DEMO jsFiddle (complete)](http://jsfiddle.net/4RVy7/4/)

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
       $(this).data('preventBehaviour', true);
    }
});
$(".draggable input").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var mdown = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    mdown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", false, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].dispatchEvent(mdown);
}).on('click', function(e){
    var $draggable = $(this).closest('.draggable');
    if($draggable.data("preventBehaviour")){
        e.preventDefault();
        $draggable.data("preventBehaviour", false)
    }
});
```

**EDIT** following comment regarding jQuery UI sortable:

Let dispatched event bubble to the sortable container:

[SORTABLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/55bxX/1/)

```
mdown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
$(this).closest('.item')[0].dispatchEvent(mdown);
```

Comment: Your second fiddle is what I'm looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: what if you are using `sortable` instead of `draggable`? I wasn't able to get it working the same way. Any chance you could take a look at this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/55bxX/

Comment: You need to allow dispatched event to bubble to container level (second parameter set to true): `mdown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);` http://jsfiddle.net/55bxX/1/